# Drag files into NetBeans to open

Tags: netbeans, drag-and-drop

I updated my Netbeans from version 7.0 to 7.1.2. One of the first things I noticed is that I can no longer drag files from my explorer window into netbeans to open it. Does anyone know why I can no longer do so? Or if you know of a setting or something to get this to work as it did in the previous version that would be great. I have scoured the internet for a solution but have not been able to find and answer.

**EDIT**

I had updated my version of NetBeans and it had worked for a couple weeks but no I am no longer able to open files by dragging them onto the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue. It looks like if NetBeans is run as administrator then you are no longer able to drag and drop file to open them in the IDE. Turning that off fixed the problem for me.

To do this in Windows 7: right click the Netbeans icon > Properties > Compatibility tab > Change Settings for All Users > unclick "Run this program as an administrator"

Answer (score 1):

Hate to say this, but on my Windows 7 box "it just works". Try upgrading your netbeans to a newer installation.

Comment: Interesting. I did upgrade to the next version and it works now.